# Have problems using Matlab coding Deep Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, multilabel-classification, multi-layer

I was trying to build a 5-layer neural network to classify a 3 classes, 178 instances and 13 features dataset. Basically I was following the guideline given [here](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Gradient_checking_and_advanced_optimization). I have written down my own code in Matlab and it can successfully run. However, the training result turns out to be very bad. The model keep predict the same class as the output. I could not found where is wrong with my code, or the model doesn't fit for the data? Could someone help me find where the problem is? Thank you very much.

My Matlab training code is shown below:

```
    %% Initialization
    numclass = 3;                  % num of class
    c = 13;                        % num of feature
    % for each layer, initialize each parameter w
      and each b to a small random value near zero
    w1 = normrnd(0,0.01,[c,10]);   % Input layer -> layer 2 (10 nodes)
    b1 = normrnd(0,0.01,[1,10]);
    w2 = normrnd(0,0.01,[10,6]);   % layer 2 -> layer 3 (6 nodes)
    b2 = normrnd(0,0.01,[1,6]);
    w3 = normrnd(0,0.01,[6,4]);    % layer 3 -> layer 4 (4 nodes)
    b3 = normrnd(0,0.01,[1,4]);
    w4 = normrnd(0,0.01,[4,numclass]); % layer 4 -> Output layer (3 nodes/class label)
    b4 = normrnd(0,0.01,[1,numclass]);

    Iter = 0;
    lambda = 0.5;     % regularization coefficient

    %% Batch Training
    while Iter < 200
        Iter = Iter+1
        d_w1 = 0; d_w2 = 0; d_w3 = 0; d_b1 = 0; d_b2 = 0; d_b3 = 0;
        d_w4 = 0; d_b4 = 0;
        for i = 1:r
        % Forward propagation
            a1 = X0(i,:);     % X0 is training data, each row represents a instance with 13 features
            % Input layer -> Layer 2
            z2 = a1*w1+b1;
            a2 = sigmoid(z2);
            % Layer 2 -> Layer 3
            z3 = a2*w2+b2;
            a3 = sigmoid(z3);
            % Layer 3 -> Layer 4
            z4 = a3*w3+b3;
            a4 = sigmoid(z4);   
            % Layer 4 -> Output Layer
            z5 = a4*w4+b4;
            a5 = sigmoid(z5);           
        % Backward propagation
            y = zeros(1,numclass);
            y(Y0(i)) = 1;    % Y0 is the training label ({1,2,3} in this case), each element indicates which class the instance belongs to 
            % Output Layer -> Layer 4
            delta5 = (-(y-a5).*d_sigmoid(z5))';
            % Output Layer -> Layer 3
            delta4 = (w4*delta5).*d_sigmoid(z4');
            % Layer 3 -> Layer 2
            delta3 = (w3*delta4).*d_sigmoid(z3');
            % Layer 2 -> Layer I
            delta2 = (w2*delta3).*d_sigmoid(z2');
        % Compute the desired partial derivatives
            d_w1 = d_w1 + (delta2*a1)';
            d_b1 = d_b1 + delta2';
            d_w2 = d_w2 + (delta3*a2)';
            d_b2 = d_b2 + delta3';
            d_w3 = d_w3 + (delta4*a3)';
            d_b3 = d_b3 + delta4';
            d_w4 = d_w4 + (delta5*a4)';
            d_b4 = d_b4 + delta5';        
        end    
        eta = 0.8;     % leraning rate
        % weights and bias updating
        w1 = w1 - eta*((1/r*d_w1)+ lambda*w1);
        b1 = b1 - eta*1/r*d_b1;
        w2 = w2 - eta*((1/r*d_w2)+ lambda*w2);
        b2 = b2 - eta*1/r*d_b2;
        w3 = w3 - eta*((1/r*d_w3)+ lambda*w3);
        b3 = b3 - eta*1/r*d_b3;
        w4 = w4 - eta*((1/r*d_w4)+ lambda*w4);
        b4 = b4 - eta*1/r*d_b4;    
    end
```

sigmoid and d_sigmoid function are shown below:

```
    function y = sigmoid(x);
       L=1;
       k=10;
       x0=0;
       y = L./(1+exp(-k*(x-x0)));
    end

    function y = d_sigmoid(x)
       tmp = sigmoid(x);
       y = tmp.*(1-tmp);
    end
```

The prediction code is shown below:

```
   %% Prediction: X1 is testing data, and Y1 is a vector of testing label
   [r,c] = size(X1);
   for i = 1:r
       A1 = X1(i,:);
   % Input layer -> Layer 2
       Z2 = A1*w1+b1;
       A2 = sigmoid(Z2);
   % Layer 2 -> Layer 3
       Z3 = A2*w2+b2;
       A3 = sigmoid(Z3);
   % Layer 3 -> Layer 4
       Z4 = A3*w3+b3;
       A4 = sigmoid(Z4);
   % Layer 4 -> Output Layer
       Z5 = A4*w4+b4;
       A5 = sigmoid(Z5);
       pred(i) = find(A5==max(A5))
   end
   error = length(find((pred'-Y1)~=0))
```

Comment: My apologize, I forgot to mention that X0 is the training dataset. Each row indicates a instance containing 13 features. Y0 is the output label {1,2,3}.

Comment: Please edit the question instead of explaining in comments.

Comment: Try with lower `eta` (perhaps 0.1) and much lower `lambda` (in fact try 0 to start - that may over-fit, but at least it would rule out a problem with it). Also can you show how you are evaluating the predicted class from `a5` just in case there is a problem at that last step?

Comment: @NeilSlater, thanks for your comment. I have added the prediction code. I also tried to change the value of learning rate and regularization coefficient as you suggested, probability did change but the result did not change.

Comment: Have you plotted any learning graphs? I cannot see any obvious problems with your code, but my earlier suggestion is based on thinking these values are not tuned. As well as `eta` and `lambda` being possibly too high, I think that for 178 instances your number of 200 epochs is maybe too low, not helped by having quite a deep network where possibly just one wider hidden layer would be perfectly ok. Usually you need to try a few variations of architecture, and plotting your learning curve (most basic one - train objective error versus iteration) may help you to see more on what is going on